# is this need further modification?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Write a function, test, that takes in three parameters: a required
>   integer, an optional boolean whose default value is True, and an
>   optional dictionary, called dict1, whose default value is {2:3, 4:5,
>   6:8}. If the boolean parameter is True, the function should test to
>   see if the integer is a key in the dictionary. The value of that key
>   should then be returned. If the boolean parameter is False, return the
>   boolean value “False”.

```py
def test(inte,boo=True,dict1={2:3, 4:5, 6:8}):
    if boo==True:
        if inte in dict1.keys():
            return dict1[inte]
```

error : Testing that test(4, False) returns False

Comment: Hello. This website is not about doing your homework, but helping solving blocking points you might run into while working on your own code. Please show what you did so far and explain the issue you have.

Comment: *If the boolean parameter is False, return the boolean value “False”.* - seems like you got it right. What is the problem?

Comment: Apparently you did not read the last sentence of the assignment. It should be pretty clear what you need to do.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve can actually be done on one line in a fun way using logical operators: `return boo and dict1[inte]`. The question doesn't state what to do if the integer is **NOT** a key in the dict, so this assumes it is...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
def test(key,b=True,dict1={2:3, 4:5, 6:8}):
    if b==True:
        if key in dict1.keys():
            return dict1[key]
    else:
        return False
```

try this one buddy